# IOS - Using CCCallBlock in Cocos2d, Asteroid Game

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

The game allow the user to control the ship and shoot down asteroids, when the asteroid gets hit by the laser i display an explosion but i need the explosion to disappear after 1 second. So I'm using CCCallBlock in Cocos2d but the Blocks don't seem to fire the method inside:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < fireArray.count; i++){

        CCSprite *fire = [fireArray objectAtIndex:i];

        for(int j = 0; j < asteroidArray.count; j++){
            CCSprite *asteroid = [asteroidArray objectAtIndex:j];


            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(fire.boundingBox, asteroid.boundingBox)) {

            CCSprite *explode = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"explode.png"];
            [explode setPosition:ccp([asteroid position].x, [asteroid position].y)];
            CGSize imageSize = explode.contentSize;
            [self addChild:explode];

            [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1],
                     [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^
                        {
                        [self removeExpode:explode];
                        }], Nil]];

            //[self stopAllActions];

            [explodeDeleteArray addObject:explode];
            [asteroidDeleteArray addObject:asteroid];
            }



        }

        }



    -(void)removeExpode:(CCSprite *)explodeObj{

        [explodeObj removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }
```

### UPDATE

I have created Explode custom Sprite but init never seems to fire as the NSLog does not print out "new explode" so that means the time never get called to make the explosion disappear:

```
                //
    //  Explode.m
    //  Asteroids
    //
    //  Created by trikam patel on 02/08/2014.
    //  Copyright 2014 trikam patel. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "Explode.h"


    @implementation Explode


    // on "init" you need to initialize your instance
    -(id) init
    {
        if( (self=[super init]) ) {

        NSLog(@"new explode");
        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                  target:self
                                selector:@selector(removeExplode)
                                userInfo:nil
                                 repeats:YES];


        }
        return self;
    }


    -(void)removeExplode{

        NSLog(@"removeExplode");
        [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];

    }

    @end


    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(fire.boundingBox, asteroid.boundingBox)) {

            Explode *explode = [[Explode alloc] initWithFile:@"explode.png"];
            [explode setPosition:ccp([asteroid position].x, [asteroid position].y)];
            [self addChild:explode];

            [asteroidDeleteArray addObject:asteroid];
    }
```

### UPDATE

Code now seems to work:

```
                        //
        //  Explode.m
        //  Asteroids
        //
        //  Created by trikam patel on 02/08/2014.
        //  Copyright 2014 trikam patel. All rights reserved.
        //

        #import "Explode.h"


        @implementation Explode


        // on "init" you need to initialize your instance
        -(id) init
        {
            if( (self=[super init]) ) {

            [super initWithFile:@"explode.png"];

            [self schedule:@selector(removeExplodeShedule:) interval:1];

            }
            return self;
        }

        -(void)removeExplodeShedule:(ccTime)res{

            [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];

            [self unschedule:@selector(removeExplodeShedule:)];

        }

        @end
```

Comment: "don't seem" meaning what? Speculation isn't helping, you need to confirm with breakpoints or NSLog statement. Also the block needn't run another method, you can simply do [explode removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES] inside the block.

Comment: ok i have removed the method and added the code from the method in the CCCallBlock, what seems to happen is that the first asteroid that gets hit the explode image shows and disappears after a second but when the other asteroids get hit the explode image displays but the explode does not disappear after a second

Comment: i have added NSLog inside the CCCallBlock and some explosions disappear and some explosions don't disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a pattern that [Apple specifically advise you avoid](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW6) (see *Patterns to Avoid* section).

There is a suggestion (on this site) that the work-around is to copy the block, however I think you are better off building the behaviour into the explosion object:

- Create a new `Explosion` object, which is a subclass of `CCSprite`.
- Move most of the initialisation of the `Explosion` object into it; all except setting its position.
- Also in the `[Explosion init]` method, schedule a 1 second timer to remove itself from the parent.

This is a much better pattern to allows the behaviour of an object to be defined in that object; however you are able to influence it if you want (for example you might pass the `timeToRemove` value as a parameter of `init`).  Welcome to Object Orientation :)

Comment: Add `[super initWithImageNamed:@"explode.png"]` to `[Explode init]` and use `Explode *explode = [[Explode alloc] init]` from outside.  Also use the cocos2d scheduling mechanism instead of `NSTimer` (optional).

Comment: Hi @Droppy, i have left the game to run for quite a while, i can see that the frames per second has dropped to 30. Has the game supposed to stay at 60 fps.

Comment: @redoc01 Ask a new question.